# session_start() is not working on my jquery mobile(register_global is off)

Tags: php, session, jquery-mobile, authentication

I am in trouble with my jquery mobile site. Its session is not working. in server register_global is off in php.ini

Someone please suggest how may I get session data on every page.I have used session_start on every page. 
Following is my php code.

```
<?php

include("include/connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){ 

// $_POST['username'] and $_POST['password'] are the param names we sent in our click event
$email = $_POST['email'];  
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
// Select eveything from the users table where username field == the username we posted and password field == the password we posted  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '" . $email . "' AND password = '" . $password . "'";  
$query = mysql_query($sql);

// If we find a match, create an array of data 
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)  
{  
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);  
    $response = array(  
        'logged' => true,
        'id'    =>$row['id'],           
        'name' => $row['fullname'],  
        'email' => $row['email']  
    );
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['name']=$response['name'];
    $_SESSION['email']=$response['email'];
    $_SESSION['id']=$response['id'];
    //redirect to homepage
    header('Location: index.php');
}  
else  
{  
    // Else the username and/or password was invalid! Create an array, json_encode it and echo it out  
    $response = array(  
        'logged' => false,  
        'message' => 'Invalid Username and/or Password'  
    );  
    //echo json_encode($response);  
    $msg="<font color='red'> invalid username or password, try again</font>";
    echo $msg;
} 
}
```

Comment: If your `connect.php` is included in every page, add `session_start();` to the top of that file.

Comment: thanks for comment but not working :(

Comment: Can you provide more details how the session is not working? Does it show any error / warning / notice?

Comment: no its not showing any error. when I echo $_SESSION[name] in this page(above code) I get the name. But I cant get it in other pages.
I have used header('Location: index.php') is this should be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

More of a comment but it may solve your issue.  The session must be started before any output is sent.  It is common practice to include this bit of code as the very first thing at the top of your file like so:

```
 <?php
 if(!isset($_SESSION)){  // don't start it if it already is
      session_start();
 }

 // ... now do stuff
```

Comment: no its not working. I think session data is not being saved. I cant get session data though I have started session on every page.